# Creative project recommendations or where to find them?

Tags: pi-3

I'm a relative newbie to Raspberry Pi and I'm trying to decide on a project that might both relate to my interests and help develop my programming skills. I've a Pi3 and have only done some small experiments running openFrameworks sketches on it with varying results.

I'm interested in creative coding, motion graphics, generative & interactive art, music & digital signal processing (DSP) etc.

I've been using TouchDesigner alot recently. I have spent some time with Processing, worked a little bit with Arduino, and beginning to use openFrameworks for its AR functionality.

I'm not a fluent programmer but I'm keen to develop my skills:

- python for web scraping and automation
- javascript for p5.js and loose web development
- C++ for openFrameworks

I came across [This paper](https://aaltodoc.aalto.fi/handle/123456789/38068) during my recent masters thesis. He basically builds a 'video synthesizer' that generates motion graphics based on voltage signals from his modular synthesizer. he built it using a RPi running GLSL shaders in openFrameworks sketches. It's very impressive but far too complex for my skillset currently. Although I'd be really interested to see if there were simpler projects in this kind of territory.

Has anybody any recommendations for projects to look into? Or maybe some reading or resources/forums that might be helpful in trying to find a project?

Hope this post is in the right place!

TIA

Comment: [The GitHub](https://github.com/sourya-sen/rPi_synth) for the project mentioned above might give a better indication.

Comment: The best source is your brain, look around and you will get ideas. A good front end that allows user drivers for the outputs in a home automation system would be nice. There are a lot of them but they are hard to interface with when using DIY components.

Comment: 1) make a pi that only mounts its sd as readonly, writing any generated outputs elsewhere (network share)  2) website server 3) network-controlled lights/outlet, etc 4) camera 5) wireless router/access point